# want to format javascript Date

Tags: javascript

want to format the javascript date currently I'm using `moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A')` to format `"2018-05-30T06:44:42.745Z"` these kind of dates which displays in this format `05/29/2018 9:09 PM` this works absolutely right but in chrome version 67 some of the unit test cases seems to fail and inconsistent.
But all test cases seem to pass chrome versions below 66

Is there any method in javascript that I can use to display the date in this format `05/29/2018 9:09 PM` instead moment js.

Have seen several posts and several methods but none of them works for the expected output above

Comment: yes, [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has many methods to getMonth, getDate, getHours etc that you can use to achieve this

Comment: maybe something like `const stringDate = date =>\`${(date.getMonth() + 1)}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()} ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()} ${date.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'}\`;` - though, that's clearly not exactly what you need

Comment: Thanks this works fine but i need it in 12 hour format not in 24 hour format

Comment: as I said, it's not **exactly** what you want ... you'll need to do some maths on the hour of course ... didn't realise you were not going to write any code at all when I offered that .... anyway - `${((date.getHours() + 11) % 12) + 1}`

Comment: You'll probably want to pad some of those values to two digits as well ... because `5/6/2018 3:4 PM` instead of `05/06/2018 3:04 PM` probably isn't what you want

Comment: i have tried tried new Date().toLocaleString('en-US') this one outputs me to 5/29/2018, 11:26:14 PM" but in fact i dont need any seconds so just trying to get rid of seconds

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US').replace(/:\d\d\s/, ' ')` - though, that has a `,` in it that you didn't specify :p ... so `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US').replace(/, |:\d\d\s/, ' ')`

Comment: Thanks that works fine